# invalid type 'float*[float]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to display the range of x and f(x) and keep f(x) in array but i always get this error:

```
invalid type 'float*[float]' for array subscript
```

can someone help me? I'm still stuck.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

using namespace std;
void displayValue(float funx[], float j, float x);

int main()
{
    float num9[]={};
    float a, r;
    displayValue(num9, a, r);

    return 0;
}
void displayValue(float funx[], float j, float x)
{
    float i;
    cout << "Please enter range of x: " << endl;
    for (i=0; i<1; i++)
    {
        cin >> x >> j;
    }
    for (float i=1; i<=160.5; i++)
    {
        x+=0.5;
        funx[i]=1/sin(x)+1/tan(x);
         //1.2 Display f(x) and x within the range
    }cout << x << " = " << funx[i] << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Do you know what `using std::cin` and `using std::cout` does?

Comment: `i` is a `float`. You can't use floats as index. Is there any reason you use `float` here instead of `int`?

Comment: Use the title to describe your problem so people can determine at a glance if they can help. "Can someone help me" is not a problem.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to pass a null array as an argument?

Comment: Arrays need integer indexes, so you'll need to use an integer value to reference them.

Comment: Also note the other warnings you should get: `float num9[]={};` is array of size zero, any access to it in `displayValue` is out of bounds and causes undefined behaviour. I suggest you use `std::vector` instead. And another error: `cout << x << " = " << funx[i] << "\n";` that's not the `i` you used in the loop before, it's the one from the top of the function, which is always 1 (because `for (i=0; i<1; i++)` runs exactly once and `i` is 1 after that)

Comment: Lastly:  It's irrelavant what values you pass for `j` and `x`, they are overwritten anyway. So they should be local variables.

Comment: What would array[1.5] do?

Comment: When doing `funx[i]` then one of `funx` or `i` needs to be an integral type (and the other a pointer to a non-void type or an array).    In your code, `funx` is a `float *` and `i` is a `float`.   Neither has an integral type, but `funx` is a pointer (or array).    The type of `i` therefore needs to be integral (e.g. `int`).   [Unless working with a class type that has an `operator[]()`, but your code is not doing that].

Answer (score 5):

The problems you're trying to solve aren't actually problems you need to solve. There's a lot going wrong in this code that can simply be removed because you're using the wrong tools.

You don't need an array here. If you did you'd *need to allocate one*, not pass in something that's empty, or you'd be using it out of bounds. In C++ for arrays like this use `std::vector`.

That being said, here's a simplified version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

// Don't add "using namespace std", that separation exists for a reason.

// Separate the math function to make it clear what's being done
float f(const float x) {
  return 1/sin(x)+1/tan(x);
}

// Define your functions before they're used to avoid having to declare
// then later define them.
void displayValue(const float min, const float max, const float step = 0.5)
{
    for (float x = min; x <= max; x += step)
    {
      // Note how the f(x) function here is a lot easier to follow
      std::cout << "f(" << x << ") = " << f(x) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter range of x: " << std::endl;

    // Capture the range values once and once only
    float min, max;
    std::cin >> min >> max;
  
    // Display over the range of values
    displayValue(min, max);

    return 0;
}
```

There's some important C++ fundamentals here:

- `float num9[]={};` is not an empty array that you can later add to, it is a **permanently zero-length array**, or in other words, it's useless.
- Pay close attention to the variables you've defined and avoid defining them twice in the same scope.
- Turn on *all* your compiler warnings while you're learning to be alerted to potential problems. C++ is full of nuances and gotchas.

Comment: i deleted my answer in favour of yours, but imho you should add a word about the `float` loop counter. In presence of rounding errors the loop might stop one iteration earlier/later than expected

Comment: @idclev463035818 It's good to note that, but floating point math is a considerable can of worms, so one thing at a time.

Comment: I would say that while not recommended, it's ok to use `using namespace std`. However, one should only use either `using namespace libraryName` and `using libraryName::functionName`, not both.